# Convert timestamp fields to ISO 8601 when push data to topic

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I have a stream that pulls data from a table in postgres with the following definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "user" (
  "_uid" UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
  "_created" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  "_updated" TIMESTAMP(3) NULL,
  "_disabled" TIMESTAMP(3) NULL,
  "display_name" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  "email" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  "password" TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

And inside ksqldb I created a SOURCE CONNECTOR like this:

```sql
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR "source-postgres-api_auth" WITH (
  "connector.class"='io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector',
  "connection.url"='jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/api_auth',
  "connection.user"='postgres',
  "connection.password"='postgres',
  "mode"='bulk',
  "topic.prefix"='source-postgres-api_auth-',
  "table.blacklist"='_changelog, _changelog_lock'
);
```

So that I can detect changes and also generate a history I have a STREAM like this:

```sql
CREATE STREAM "stream-api_auth-user" (
  "_uid" STRING,
  "_created" TIMESTAMP,
  "_updated" TIMESTAMP,
  "_disabled" TIMESTAMP,
  "display_name" STRING,
  "email" STRING,
  "password" STRING
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'source-postgres-api_auth-user',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO'
);
```

And I created a TABLE from this STREAM:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "table-api_auth-user" WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'table-api_auth-user',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO'
) AS SELECT 
  "_uid",
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET("_created") AS "_created",
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET("_updated") AS "_updated",
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET("_disabled") AS "_disabled",
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET("display_name") AS "display_name",
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET("email") AS "email",
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET("password") AS "password"
FROM "stream-api_auth-user"
GROUP BY "_uid"
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Lastly, I have a SYNC to elasticsearch like this:

```sql
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR "sync-elasticsearch-user" WITH (
  'connector.class' = 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
  'connection.url' = 'http://elasticsearch:9200',
  'type.name' = 'kafka-connect',
  'topics' = 'table-api_auth-user'
);
```

My problem is that when I look in elasticsearch, the fields that are of TIMESTAMP type are coming in as numbers and I realized that the topic data that the TABLE is using that is being converted to numbers and not to ISO 8601:

```
ksql> print "table-api_auth-user";
Key format: HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: AVRO or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2022/12/01 21:13:36.844 Z, key: [a2d9ff97-2c95-4da0-98e0-5492@7293921773168638261/-], value: {"_created":1669926069726,"_updated":null,"_disabled":null,"display_name":"Super User","email":"superuser@email.com","password":"4072d7365233d8ede7ca8548543222dfb96b17780aa8d6ff93ab69c0985ef21fc8105d03590a61b9"}, partition: 0
rowtime: 2022/12/01 21:13:36.847 Z, key: [b60448d2-e518-4479-9aff-2734@3631370472181359666/-], value: {"_created":1669916433173,"_updated":1669916803008,"_disabled":1669916803008,"display_name":"Cremin 7a8c281c4bed","email":"Byrne.8dd1dcf3bfa4@yahoo.com","password":"e89af05eae87f0667eba762fdd382ce942bb76b796b8fe20d9e71f142bac9f7a6fbbfc6b51d4527e"}, partition: 0
```

Is there anything I can do so that when the table sends the data to the topic, these fields of type timestamp are converted to ISO 8601?

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the fields from the Elasticsearch side via ingest pipeline:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

I read there is no option to specify ingest pipeline on the sink connector:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/72

So you have to create an index template that will capture the name of the index, and apply the pipeline.

**Step 1: Create the ingest pipeline**

I will use the date processor to convert your format (UNIX_MS) to ISO8601

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-processor.html

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/parsedate
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "date": {
        "field": "date",
        "formats": [
          "UNIX_MS"
        ],
        "target_field": "date_converted",
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Test output (date field vs date_converted:

```
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "doc": {
        "_index": "_index",
        "_id": "_id",
        "_version": "-3",
        "_source": {
          "date": 1669916803008,
          "date_converted": "2022-12-01T17:46:43.008Z"
        },
        "_ingest": {
          "timestamp": "2022-12-02T07:54:02.731666786Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Step 2: Create the index template**

Assuming your index name is table-api_auth-user*

```
PUT _index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["table-api_auth-user*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index.default_pipeline": "parsedate"
    }
  }
}
```

From now, everytime you send a document to this index: table-api_auth-user* , will apply the ingest pipeline you set at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved it in another way, converting the field in KSQL to ISO 8601 format and recreating the index in ES defining the date type fields

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. The close to the source you can solve the issue the better!